# Redux Store Not Persist ( Metro Reload Clear the State )

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-persist, metro-bundler

I have implemented redux store like below, but persisting state is not working properly.

```js
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

const middleware = [thunk];

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: middleware,
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

My rootReducer like bellow,

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import tokenReducer from './token';
import authReducer from './auth';
import tabBarReducer from './tabBar';
import workListReducer from './home/workList';
import translationReducer from './translation';
import userReducer from './user';
import headersReducer from './home/headers';

export default combineReducers({
  token: tokenReducer,
  auth: authReducer,
  tabBar: tabBarReducer,
  workList: workListReducer,
  translation: translationReducer,
  user: userReducer,
  headers: headersReducer,
});
```

Every time I refresh metro (*pressing "R"*) clears the current state and the app goes back to the initial state.

Comment: not sure why you store is not persisting, can you once try using whitelist on any reducer and verify whether that particular reducer is persisting in the store? By default all the reducers need to persist, this is just to debug it.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the The `PersistGate` HOC inside the provider?
if not it will be something like this ,

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <PersistGate
    loading={Loader}
    persistor={persistor}
    onBeforeLift={onBeforeLift}
  >
    {children}
  </PersistGate>
</Provider>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using the same way, but not working